# How do I reset my libraries back to original condition?

Tags: arduino-ide, installation

How do I reset my arduino installation back to its original state? i.e., no extra downloaded libraries, etc.  If I delete Documents/Arduino/libraries is there any other state that needs to be cleaned up?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Did you use the installer or the portable zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delete the Documents -> Arduino -> Libraries to remove all your libraries.
2. Delete the User -> AppData -> Local -> Arduino15 folder to remove all the preferences.
3. Uninstall Arduino IDE.
4. Install a fresh one.

Answer (score 0):

Directory to suppress for reset config.

- C:\Users\YourName\.arduinoIDE
- C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Arduino15
- C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Programs\Arduino IDE
- C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\arduino-ide-updater
- C:\Users\YourName\Documents\Arduino
- C:\Users\YourName\AppData\AppData\Roaming\Arduino IDE
- C:\Users\YourName\AppData\AppData\Roaming\arduino-ide